# How to run the node.js file in net beans?

Tags: node.js, netbeans

In net beans i have installed node.js pulgin.But my sample node program is not working.Im getting error.
This is my sample code

```
    var http = require("http");
    http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});

    res.end("Hai! welcome to node.js...!\n");

      }).listen(3030, "localhost");



   console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:3030/");/*
```

While running the above program.Im getting following error.

```
                  module.js:340
                 throw err;
                     ^
         Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.0.1\hello.js'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
        at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
        at startup (node.js:119:16)
        at node.js:903:3
```

But the above program works from the terminal.

Comment: did you make this work ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From my knowledge, currently there are 2 netbeans plugins for Node.js

**The one you're using**
http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/36653/nodejs

(very simple plugin, it doesn't do much (I used it on an older version of netbeans), and I can't get it to work on netbeans 7.4)

and a second one:

**NetBeans NodeJS Plugin**
https://github.com/timboudreau/nb-nodejs

I want to suggest that you switch to the second one, because:

- it actually works
- it provides a "node project type"
- more

Comment: any idea how to use nb-nodejs on existing source?  It doesn't have that option.

Comment: Note for existing projects you can simply open the folder as a project: "Any* folder with a package.json file is automatically a project - no special "import" functionality is needed for projects with existing sources - the plugin just uses the normal NodeJS package metadata. Try opening a directory which contains a package.json as a project using Open Project - you'll find it works"

Comment: So, did you answer your own question? :) I'm confused.

Comment: Yip, found my own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Netbeans Node support does not appear quite ready for prime time. Problem: the "standard" (danielkec) Node plugin does not know about projects, so you will have to create a bogus (Html5??) project to use it.
Problem2: Tim Boudreau's Node plugin does nicely with project creation and code completion but it has zero support for debugging (Tim prefers inserting print statements in the code).
So at this point (Netbeans 8), I would not recommend Netbeans for Node.js work.

Answer (score 1):

In NetBeans go to `Tools >> Options >> Miscellaneous >> Node.js`

and change default command to

`node ${workingdir}\${selectedfile}`

Answer (score 1):

[Netbeans 8.1](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/81/) now has Node.js debugging support. Simply right click the file and click 'Debug'.

[image]

Comment: i am able to debug single file as above but no option to start debug on project. any links to that?

Answer (score 0):

Your Node code looks fine.  Have you really created the hello.js file in the NetBeans folder as it looks like Node cannot find the file in this folder?

If you go to the node options in NetBeans, you need to make sure you are changing directory to the folder that contains your application source.  This is done in NetBeans by setting the "Default Run Command" to be something like:

cd ${workingdir};

/usr/local/bin/node ${selectedfile};

Where you need to set the path to node as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

In NetBeans go to *Tools >> Options >> Miscellaneous >> Node.js*

and change default command to:

`node ${workingdir}\${selectedfile}`

You should also add *lessc* file path to your netbeans. In netbeans go to:

*Tools >> Options >> Miscellaneous >> CSS Preprossessors*

And add path to your node *lessc* file path.

It will be located in `C:\Users\{your user name}\AppData\Roaming\npm\lessc.cmd`

If it is not found then you have to install it by command prompt by following code:

`npm install less -g`

Comment: To add node.js plugin to your netbeans go tools >> plugins >> available plugins 
Find node.js and install it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, not a lot of resources available!! finally found one which solved.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b3giUSvRjPc
https://joanpaon.wordpress.com/2015/08/13/how-to-setup-nodejs-with-netbeans-8-1beta/

and
install nodejs from nodejs.org
in the windown cmd run the command
c:>npm install express-generator -g

fortunately, netbeans has the search option to find the necessary resources for node js.