# netbeans - 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, netbeans, less

I would like to use CSS preprocessor (less) in my project so I installed node.js and less ("npm install -g less"). In netbeans I pointed out the path to the file lessc.cmd and the problem now is that when compiling I get the message

> 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,  operable
>   program or batch file.

What to do with that?

Comment: Is node in your path?

Comment: You need to set `node.js` in your environment variable `Path`!

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25914314/1596547